# Angular 4 - BehaviourSubject not returning json data properly

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to creating a global service in angular app with `BehaviorSubject`.

I have created a method in this service where I have defined a HTTP get method and loading JSON file.

Now the issue I'm facing is when I'm subscribing this `BehaviourSubject` as `asObservable` in any component and assign the result to a particular variable in the typescript file, the HTML template renders this value correctly via structured Directive `*ngFor` but when I'm trying to get the same value in typescript file, it does not work.

For example;

When I'm trying to print this value

```
console.log(this.data.boxes.length);
```

then it gives me an error

> [ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]

and when I'm trying to print this value without length

```
console.log(this.data.boxes);
```

it gives me a proper value of an array in the console panel.

Now If I change `BehaviorSubject` to `Subject`, then its working fine means I am also getting `length` value.

However, I want to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve it?

Comment: My first thought is that BehaviourSubject will only return you the last value, so that’s why you might not have length because it’s returning one single value. Is there a specific reason for wanting a BehaviourSubject instead of a regular Subject?

Comment: It would be helpful to have more code in this example. It's hard to visualize what you are trying to do here. Can you provide the relevant code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Behavior subject is emitting current value to subscriber even if subject next is not called before subscription, in other words:

yours subscription is subscribed to subject before first "next" value. I assume that initial value of behavior subject is undefined or similar, so that first value that is emitted to subscriber is causing error. 
Could you check declaration of subject and ensure that initial value is in correct form, like:

```
public exampleSubject = new BeahviourSubject<yourType[]>(<yourType[]>[]);
```